# Android - startService immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm looking for a way to start a service immediately when it is called (I have notice that it can take some time if a network operation is carried out for example). 
This is how it is called now:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(application, SomeIntentService.class);
application.startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you call `application.startService()`? Usually the `startService()`is the correct way of starting a service and the `onCreate()` method should be called immediately.

But keep in mind that an IntentService handles all requests on a single worker thread and that it will only handle one request at a time - so if you call your service multiple times and a previous request has not been finished yet (e.g a network task), it will enqueue the new task which will be executed once the previous one has finished.

Comment: It is called from a class (and gets the Application as a parameter). So lets say that I'm calling this intentService many times on different actions, so when I want to call this immediate action I need to call a different service (not  `SomeIntentService.class`) so it can start immediately. correct?

Comment: You should think of a different implementation strategy when you want to run multiple background tasks immediately. Maybe you want to have a look at AsyncTask or you could use threads...

Comment: I actually don't need them all immediately, just one. Can I give some priority to the services?